# Autowiring is not working if test listener used in JUnit & Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit4

I found, that uncommenting test listener annotation causes test not working below (autowired member is not initialized and NullPointerException occurs):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestExecutionListenerTry2._Config.class)
//@TestExecutionListeners({TestExecutionListenerTry2._Listener.class})
public class TestExecutionListenerTry2 {

   public static class Bean1 {
      {
         System.out.println("Bean1 constructor");
      }

      public void method() {
         System.out.println("method()");
      }
   }

   @Configuration
   public static class _Config {

      @Bean
      public Bean1 bean1() {
         return new Bean1();
      }

   }

   public static class _Listener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {
      @Override
      public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("prepareTestInstance");
      }

      @Override
      public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("beforeTestClass");
      }
   }

   @Autowired
   public Bean1 bean1;

   @Test
   public void testMethod() {
      bean1.method();
   }
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you provide a `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation, you overwrite the default list of [`TestExecutionListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html) types, which includes a [`DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/support/DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.html) that handles dependency injection.

The default types are declared in the `TestExecutionListener` javadoc:

> Spring provides the following out-of-the-box implementations (all of
>   which implement `Ordered`):
>
> - `ServletTestExecutionListener`
> - `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener`
> - `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener`
> - `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`
> - `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener`

Either register those as well. Or merge yours and the defaults with the technique outlined in the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tel-config-merging)

> To avoid having to be aware of and re-declare all default listeners,
>   the `mergeMode` attribute of `@TestExecutionListeners` can be set to
>   `MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS`. `MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS` indicates that
>   locally declared listeners should be merged with the default
>   listeners.

So your annotation would look like

```
@TestExecutionListeners(value = { TestExecutionListenerTry2._Listener.class },
        mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
```

Comment: I'm getting the null exception on a member in my TestExecutionListener even when using the MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS, like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204840/spring-dependency-injection-into-spring-testexecutionlisteners-not-working  What's the difference?