# Spring dependency injection into Spring TestExecutionListeners not working

Tags: java, spring-test

How can I use Spring dependency injection into a TestExecutionListener class I wrote extending AbstractTestExecutionListener?

Spring DI does not seem to work with TestExecutionListener classes.
Example of issue:

The AbstractTestExecutionListener:

```
class SimpleClassTestListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    protected String simplefield; // does not work simplefield = null

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("simplefield " + simplefield);
    }
}
```

Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example*" })
class SimpleConfig {

    @Bean
    public String simpleField() {
        return "simpleField";
    }

}
```

The JUnit Test file:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SimpleConfig.class })
@TestExecutionListeners(mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS, listeners = {
    SimpleClassTestListener.class })
public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        assertTrue();
    }
}
```

As highlighted in the code comment, when I run this, it will print "simplefield null" because simplefield never gets injected with a value.

Comment: Also I added @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example*" }) in configuration.

Comment: I don't like to use testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(...).

Comment: I am seeing this issue too in a new project with Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add autowiring for the whole TestExecutionListener.

```
@Override
public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    testContext.getApplicationContext()
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .autowireBean(this);
    // your code that uses autowired fields
}
```

Check [sample project in github](https://github.com/IlyaZinkovich/spring-test-autowiring-test-execution-listeners).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Spring Boot 2 using

```
estContext.getApplicationContext()
        .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
        .autowireBean(this)
```

was triggering the creation of the Spring context before the `@SpringBootTest` base class was created. This missed then some critical configuration parameters in my case. I had to use `testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(` in `beforeTestClass` for getting a bean instance.